# How do I change elements of a navigation bar based on url?

Tags: html, css

This is a basic question. A lot of websites have navigation bars that change color to indicate which page you are on. How do I do this?

I looked for a long time only to find a couple solutions: javascript with onclick or CSS focus. However, they don't work when I navigate away to subpages. What's the best solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "navigation bars that change color to indicate which page you are on", but is this what you are looking for? [Meta Theme Color and Trickery](https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/)

Comment: @MarkHanna I mean a navbar lik this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: In the example you point at an additional class ('active') has been added to the tab in the navbar. This can be done by whatever is creating that page - the backend will 'know' which page it is creating.

Comment: @AHaworth Your method only works for a templating framework right? Is there anyway to do this in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

A rather simplistic way of doing something in the frontend is to get the current href and iterate through the hrefs in the navbar's anchor links to find a match.

This is very basic code to get you started.

```
<style>
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<nav> 
<ul>
<li><a href="https://domain/home.htmll">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://domain/about.htmll">About</a></li>
<li><a href="https://domain/contact.htmll">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<script>
const iAmHere = window.location.href;
alert('This is the current URL: ' + iAmHere);
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
anchors.forEach(anchor => {
  if (anchor.href == iAmHere) {anchor.classList.add('active');}
  else {anchor.classList.remove('active'); }
}); 
</script>
```

You will want to ensure that you are matching like for like - e.g. if the hrefs in the anchor elements do not spell out the full URL you'll want to look for just part of it to match. Also you may or may not want to ignore any keys sent with the url. This all depends on your use case.